# Is "La Tabki Ya Saghiri" an original Digimon Arabic song?

Tags: music, digimon

There's a *Digimon* song in Arabic called [**لا تبكي يا صغيري**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sztDUuN3Nsk) (*La Tabki Ya Saghiri*). I'm not sure if it's a *Digimon* Arabic original song or if it exists in Japanese.

Is this an original song or a dubbed of an existing *Digimon* song?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is **3 Primary Colors** by Tamers, an insert song of *Digimon Tamers* and the 10th track of [*Digimon Tamers: Single Best Parade*](http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/Digimon_Tamers:_Single_Best_Parade) album.